# Detect if app was activated by AppleScript

Tags: swift, applescript

Is there a way to tell if my application was activated by AppleScript?

ie, I have the following AppleScript

```
tell application "MyApp"
  activate
end tell
```

Is there a way I can tell it was AppleScript and not a User manually clicking on the app to activate it?

```
//func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ notification: Notification)
//or
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
  switch someLaunchMethod {
    case .click:
      print("user clicked")
    case .applescript:
      print("activated from AppleScript")
  }
}
```

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: The script calls the delegate method the same as clicking on the app - what exactly are you tying to do?

Comment: It's for Analytics, how many users are scripting my app

Comment: I don’t use Swift, but one option would be to check if the application sending the AppleEvent is not the Finder or Dock.

Comment: @red_menace Do you have an example of that in another language?

Comment: You can use something similar to the answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57064023 - the idea is to get the bundle identifier for the app sending a (re)open AppleEvent, and if it is not the Finder or Dock (or itself), it would most likely be from a script.